# Using Event Emitter to pass data from Cart to Checkout Page with Angular

Tags: angular, event-handling, output, angular-event-emitter

I am currently working on a shopping cart, and i would like to pass the quantity typed on the cart page and other data to the check-out page.
I have tried different approach but i was unable to get it.

Here is my **Cart.component.ts**

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  @Output() quantityChange = new EventEmitter();

 
  constructor(
    private data: DataService,
    private rest: RestApiService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.cartItems.forEach(data => {
      this.quantities.push(1);
    });
  }
   valueChanged(){
     this.quantities = this.quantities
     this.quantityChange.emit(this.quantities)
   }
```

and my **cart.component.html**

```
<div class="col-1 mt-5 mt-md-0 p-0 induc">
  <input type="number" class="form-control text-left boy" 
 [(ngModel)]="quantities[i]">
</div>            
...
<h5 class="text-right">Total:
  <span class="ml-1 font-weight-bold text-danger"> ₦ {{ cartTotal}}
  </span>
</h5>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems somethings are missing in your code, like how is invoke `valueChange`, an empty `input`, etc. But it is somehow a common issue about parent - child interaction.

You already establish half of the interaction by defining the output `quantityChange` in the child. Now you just need to capture that output in the parent. Something like this should work,

**checkout-page.component.html** (assuming that `app-cart` is the component name)

```
...
<app-cart (quantityChange)="cartQuantityChange($event)"></app-cart>
...
```

**checkout-page.component.ts**

```
export class CheckoutPage {
  ...
  cartQuantityChange(quantities: number[]) {
    // do something with quantities
  }
  ...
}
```

[Angular Docs - Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)